# AWS console - This site cannot be reached - Only on my PC

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, chrome

I have an AWS insatance and whenever I go to the console page, ie: https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com on a browser I get the message:

```
This site can’t be reached
us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com unexpectedly closed the connection.
```

The front end site that is being ran off the instance is completely fine. As well as connecting via SSH. No problems at all. Only on the AWS console browser page does this happen. I should also mention: 
1) This behavior only happens on my PC. On my mac and my co-workers PC it loads fine (same IP). 
2) I have tried all browsers (chrome, FF, Opera, IE, edge) and all give the same 'cannot reach site' error. 
3) I have aggressively cleared any and all browser cashe. Even reinstalled Chrome.

Any ideas as to what could be blocking my connection to the console?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Press F12 in your browser, refresh the page and review the debugger window. This will help you figure what errors are actually happening.

Comment: You don't need to post questions twice. I have suggested the [other question](https://serverfault.com/questions/899531/aws-console-closes-connection-in-browser) be deleted.

Comment: Try disabling any antivirus software or firewalls temporarily.

Comment: Inspecting (F12) does no good because the web page is completely blank and not loaded due to the site being unreachable.

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve this issue? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issues, flushing dns cache worked for me.

```
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

You can follow-  [https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/this-site-cant-be-reached/#:~:text=Restart%20Your%20Internet%20Connection,often%20resolve%20this%20problem%20quickly](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/this-site-cant-be-reached/#:%7E:text=Restart%20Your%20Internet%20Connection,often%20resolve%20this%20problem%20quickly).

Comment: `mDNS` is not the DNS cache, at all (multicast DNS is a DNS resolution inside a gapped network with no server), you're for sure encountering other issues that aren't related to OP